# How can I set editing= NO; in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

How can I set editing= NO; in UITextField ?

Comment: note, these days (2013) you can just do it in the InterfaceBuilder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set it like

```
[yourTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Swift Update:

```
yourTextField.setUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: `yourtextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`   modern syntax

Comment: I think it will prevent selection of text. So the option with implementing delegate methos shouldChange seems a bit better for the most of use cases

Answer (score 2):

Also you can implement the  protocol and implements this method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   return NO;
}
```

Doing this any UITextField in associated XIB will be editable, but you gain the hability for checking any properties or doing some business logic inside for enable/disable text editing.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if (condition)
       return NO;
   else 
       return YES;
}
```

I hope this helps you

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to hide the UITextField, just do:

```
[UITextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: resignFirstResponder is used to dismiss the keyboard, not to hide the UITextField.

Answer (score -2):

Use this piece of code

```
[textField setEditable:NO];
```

Comment: UITextField may not respond to setEditable

Comment: Application gets crashed as there is no such function setEditable

Comment: There is no such function like this.